# Angularjs $interval: Using a callback function as a param into the pass in function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intervals

Sorry for the confusing title, I really don't how how to phrase this question.  I've tried googling a ton of different phrases but the same results keep coming up which isn't the what I'm looking for.

First of, I'm new to angularjs and javascript so apologies if I miss something pretty simple.

Looking at the interval documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

What I'm trying to do is call the $interval service like the following:

controller.js:

```
(function() {
    function controller($scope, $interval, myService) {

        var stop;
        function handleCallback( myParams ) {
            //do stuff with myParams
            //call stopInterval function if neccessary.
        }

        $scope.doSomething = function() {
            stop = $interval(myService.doWork, 5000, 0, handleCallback);
        };


        var stopInterval = function() {
            if (angular.isDefined( stop ) ) {
                $interval.cancel( stop );
                stop = undefined;
            };
        };
    }

    angular.module( 'myApp' ).controller( 'controller', controller);
})();
```

my-service.js

```
(function() {
    function myService($q, $http) {
        myService.doWork = function( callback ) {
            var dfd = $q.defer();
            $http.get('url').success( function( response ) {
                //Would parse the response into an appropriate response
                //before calling the callback method with it.
                callback( response );
                dfd.resolve( response );
            }).error( function( response ) ) {
                //will add an error callback once I get this working
                dfd.reject( response );
            });

            return dfd.promise;
        }

        return myService
    }

    angular.module( 'myApp' ).factory( 'myService', myService);
})();
```

When I step through this, and I start hitting the myService.doWork( callback ) method, callback is never a function but just a number and every time it's hit, the number is incremented by one.

I'm not sure where that number is coming from but I'm guessing I'm not setting up the $interval call properly.  Looking at the angular documentation, the Pass param type says "*" so I'm assuming it means any type is supported and that functions are valid params.  Is this not the case?  Is it not possible to pass in a function as a param to fn for the $interval service?

-Thanks in advance for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a promise from your service. Any particular reason you wouldn't do the following?

```
var stop = $interval(function () { 
  myService
   .doWork()
   .then(function (res) {
     //if promise is successful, res is your data
     $interval.cancel(stop)
   })
   .catch(function (err) {
     //if promise was rejected, err is your servers error message
   });
}, 5000);
```

Seems like you are spreading your logic out unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I didn't even think of an approach like this and implementing my logic this way definitely makes my code a lot cleaner and simpler.  I've updated my code and it works great but I'm still curious why my sample code doesn't work.  My method does return a promise but I don't get why that affects the params parameter I'm passing in.  It shouldn't matter to the function params what the return type is, right?

Comment: Looking at angularjs docs, there are 5 parameters to interval: $interval(fn, delay, [count], [invokeApply], [Pass]);  You seem to only be sending 4 parameters. 

If I helped, please upvote and mark as correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `$timeout` is correct. Your definition of the service isn't.

Try returning an object in which you define your doWork method. Do the service definition like this:

```
angular.module( 'myApp' ).factory( 'myService', myService);

function myService() {
    var doWork = function() {
         ...
    };
    return { doWork: doWork };
}
```

Comment: You're right, in my actual code I'm doing something similar.  I've updated my post to reflect what my actual code is doing.  Apologies for missing this important detail.